# What does it mean for a linear or a nonlinear system to be degenerate?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of degeneracy in linear and nonlinear systems. I have read chapters where system stability is discussed in my linear algebra/controls engineering textbooks, but the definition of degeneracy is not discussed in any of them. For instance, if you have the nonlinear system

$
\begin{cases}
 \dot{x}_1 = f_1(x_1, x_2)\\
 \dot{x}_2 = f_2(x_1, x_2)\\
\end{cases}
$

and the system is linearized to resemble $\dot{x} \approx Ax + Bu$, the eigenvalues of $A$ can be computed to determine stability. So, if $\lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_2 < 0$, the system is a *stable degenerate node*; similarly if $\lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_2 > 0$, the system is an unstable degenerate node. In this context, what does degeneracy mean? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Degenerate in this instance means that one of the eigenvalues is zero.

If a *linear* system is degenerate, it means the steady state is not isolated.  There is a one-parameter family of steady states corresponding to the eigenvector with zero eigenvalue.

If the linearization of a *nonlinear* system is degenerate, it means that the linearization does not contain all the information on how solutions behave near the steady state; a zero eigenvalue could correspond to (sub-exponential) growth or decay, or the existence of one-parameter family of steady states.